# Dell Laptop Inspiron Cables - Check the following cable, jumper, connection, polyfuse, or sensor; LCD Cable Error Code 2000-0415 Validation Code 75189

Tags: dell-inspiron, lcd, diagnostic, windows-error-reporting, blank-screen

Here is my laptop's System technical details:

OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Home

Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621

Other OS Description    Not Available

OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation

System Name

System Manufacturer Dell Inc.

System Model    Inspiron 5515

System Type x64-based PC

System SKU  0A78

Processor   AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics, 1801 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s)

BIOS Version/Date   Dell Inc. 1.16.0, 4/12/2023

SMBIOS Version  3.3

Embedded Controller Version 255.255

BIOS Mode   UEFI

BaseBoard Manufacturer  Dell Inc.

BaseBoard Product   0KDKG8

BaseBoard Version   A00

Platform Role   Mobile

Secure Boot State   On

PCR7 Configuration  Elevation Required to View

Windows Directory   C:\WINDOWS

System Directory    C:\WINDOWS\system32

Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1

Locale  United States

Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.22621.2506"

User Name

Time Zone   Pacific Standard Time

Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB

Total Physical Memory   15.4 GB

Available Physical Memory   9.32 GB

Total Virtual Memory    18.2 GB

Available Virtual Memory    10.7 GB

Page File Space 2.88 GB

Page File   C:\pagefile.sys

Kernel DMA Protection   Off

Virtualization-based security   Not enabled

Windows Defender Application Control policy Enforced

Windows Defender Application Control user mode policy   Off

Device Encryption Support   Elevation Required to View

Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes

Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes

Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    Yes

Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes

Even when I turned on my Dell laptop, its LCD screen is completely blank (i.e., black screen )

Therefore, I used an HDMI cable to connect the laptop to my LCD TV monitor:

I ran the Diagnostics, and it gave the following error:

[image]

Could someone please tell me how to resolve the aforementioned error?

Comment: What did Support say when you contacted them?

Comment: I did Not contact support.  Instead of going thorough all the nightmarish bureaucratic process, could you please tell me if there is an alternative way of resolve said error?  Thanks.

Comment: OK. Let's set out what you already know… Symptoms; screen black. Automatic diagnosis; cable fault. Conclusion - do what it says on the diagnosis & check the cables. If the cables look OK, contact support, or take it to a repair shop [depending on warranty status].

Comment: cable fault?  Oh, do I have to open up the laptop?  That's going to be a headache.

Comment: Had you not yet grasped that? I know it's a bit of a multi-applicable message but essentially it says "Cables - check the bit of hardware mentioned here: -> LCD Cable."

Comment: @user1338998 - If you can’t figure it out you’ll have to find someone who can figure it out. Software is detecting a hardware fault. A black screen suggests a hardware fault. Conclusion: You have a hardware fault